# Differentiating $a^{f(x)}$ for a natural number $a$.

Tags: calculus

This is more of a simple question for anyone who has done calculus, though I am learning calculus right now and just wanted to know how you prove the derivative of $a^{f(x)}$ if $a$ is a natural number. The derivative of $a^x$ is very simple for me to understand though no matter where I look on the internet, I can't find proof for $a^{f(x)}$.

I tried using $\frac{d}{dx} a^x=ln(a)*a^x$, so that $\frac{d}{dx} a^{f(x)}=ln(a)*a^{f(x)}$, though the actual derivative is actually $d/dx a^{f(x)}=ln(a)*(a^{f(x)})*f'(x)$.

I'm not really sure where the extra $f'(x)$ comes from.

Your help and answers are strongly appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you familiar with the chain rule?

Comment: Yes. I am also familiar with how to prove it.

Comment: It comes from the fact that $a^x$ is not $a^{f(x)}$.

Comment: If you know how to find the derivative for $a^x$, then just do the same for $a^{f(x)}$, as they are the same if $f(x)=x$. You should then be able to find a general formula. 
It should help that d/dx of x is 1, which is the term that you ignored, while deriving the general formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option:

$g(x):=a^{f(x)}$; $a>0$;

Take $\log_e$ of both sides:

$\log g(x)=f(x) \log a$;

Differentiate both sides, and recall

$(\log g(x))'= \dfrac{1}{g(x)}\cdot g'(x)$ (Chain rule):

$\dfrac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=f'(x)\log a$;

Multiply by $g(x)$:

$g'(x)=(\log a) f'(x)g(x)=$

$(\log a) f'(x)a^{f(x)}$;

Comment: +1, though could u explain the second and third step in more detail. I’m not sure what base the log is in.

Comment: Oh nvm I get the second step it’s just the third t step I don’t get

Comment: JC12.Give me a moment, I edit.

Comment: JC12.Better now?

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful!!!

Comment: JC12. Sure ok? Usually when using $\log $ it is meant to be base e, unless otherwise stated. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

If $a \in \mathbb N$, then

$$g(x)=a^{f(x)}= e^{\ln(a) \cdot f(x)}.$$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I get that it’s then equal to a*(e^f(x)) though I am not sure where to go from there...

Answer (score 1):

You should write
$$
a^{f(x)}=e^{f(x)\ln a}
$$
then, remembering that $(e^x)'=e^x$, you will get
$$
[a^{f(x)}]'=a^{f(x)}\ln a f'(x).
$$